# Median on a set of non-integer values is being displayed as integers

Tags: powerbi

I'm presenting visualizations of time to complete different tasks. Some the data is heavily skewed by certain tasks which take much longer than the rest, so I thought it would be a good idea to show both the means and the medians, to demonstrate where that skew is present. I have one page of visualizations for the mean, and an identical page where the mean has been replaced by the median. However, when PowerBI Calculates the medians, it seems to be giving me integer values, where I would like it to display the full decimal value.

Here's screenshots of each page (I've had to black out the labels for confidentiality reasons).

[image: means]

[image: medians]

And a snippet of the data so you can see it's being read in as decimal numbers.

[image]

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the measures you're using for Mean and Median

Comment: The data is being read as decimal data, but is not explicitly declared as such (via change type → decimal number).Could you try if that fixes your problem?